# Compressed static file serving in flask

Tags: python, performance, file-system, flask

Flask comes with built-in [static file serving](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.send_static_file), but compression support is completely missing. I think the way [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/base.html#compression-support) implements it and compress files during builds. The following should serve the compressed static files.

```
import os

from flask import current_app, request, safe_join


def send_compressed_file(filename, formats=[('br', 'br'), ('gzip', 'gz')]):
    if not current_app.has_static_folder:
        raise RuntimeError('No static folder for the current application')
    accept_encoding = request.headers.get('Accept-Encoding', None)
    if not accept_encoding:
        return current_app.send_static_file(filename)
    encodings = [encoding.trim() for encoding in accept_encoding.split(',')]
    for format, extension in formats:
        compressed = filename + extension
        if format in encodings and os.path.exists(safe_join(current_app.static_folder, compressed)):
            return current_app.send_static_file(compressed)
    return current_app.send_static_file(filename)
```

Than I would simply hook it into the `Flask` object.

```
def production():
    app.view_functions['static'] = send_compressed_file
    return app
```

Because it is very performance critical (every static file request hits this function) I would like to get some performance suggestions. Promblems that I encountered myself:

- I think `os.path.exists` is not efficient? How could I store file paths better?

Comment: This is an amazing question and I'm also interested in an answer to how best to send compressed static files on Flask.